# jQuery, random div order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I have this jQuery and HTML http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/30/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="white"></div>
    </div>​
$("div.container div").each(function(){
    var color = $(this).attr("class");
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: color});
});
```

I am trying to randomise the order, so the `div.container div` is in any random position, meaning not the same position it started. and the div must remain within the `div.container`

I have tried 
http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/32/
http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/20/ and more functions I found on the net but non are working

​how can I get the div's to display in a random order

Comment: It *seems* to work okay, once the typo's fixed (you had `.addCass` instead of `.addClass`): [Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UgX3u/35/).

Comment: +1 sorry for being a nonce :(.

Comment: Absolutely! 'cause I've *never* done that! ...not ever... *runs* =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/33/

```
$("div.container div").sort(function(){
    return Math.random()*10 > 5 ? 1 : -1;
}).each(function(){
    var $t = $(this),
        color = $t.attr("class");
    $t.css({backgroundColor: color}).appendTo( $t.parent() );
});
```

`.sort` is applied to jQuery like this:

```
$.fn.sort = [].sort
```

Since it doesn't perform like other jQuery methods, it isn't documented. That does mean it is subject to change, however I doubt it will ever change. To avoid using the undocumented method, you could do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/37/

```
var collection = $("div.container div").get();
collection.sort(function() {
    return Math.random()*10 > 5 ? 1 : -1;
});
$.each(collection,function(i,el) {
    var color = this.className,
        $el = $(el);
    $el.css({backgroundColor: color}).appendTo( $el.parent() );
});
```

Comment: As of today (Sept. 2013) this doesn't work anymore.  I don't get a jQuery Error, it simply doesn't work :-( dbl checked the code.  I have tried it here www.stupidwebtools.com .  On the other hand the function `shuffle(o)` works great.

Comment: Well, it still works in the fiddle, even when i choose the latest jquery version. most of the work is done by native javascript methods, therefore there isn't any reason for it to stop working.

Comment: Hi there, what if I want to random just a few div with class name "random" inside the div container? Since inside my div container has several more div, but I only want a few div to be random inside container. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

```
var $container = $("div.container");
$container.html(shuffle($container.children().get()));

function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

Shuffle function found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/849)

**Updated:**
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/27EbQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes you have to work with elements already on a page with classes assigned to them:

```
var classes = [];

// Populate classes array
// e.g., ["yellow", "red", "green", "blue", "pink", "orange", "black", "white"]
$('div.container').children().each(function (i, v) {
    classes.push(v.className);
});

// Assign random color to each div
$('div.container').children().each(function (i, v) {
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length)
    $(v).css({backgroundColor: classes.splice(color,1)});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UgX3u/40/